# Action is not dispatched again after the props change in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following React Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {loadJobTitleSkills} from '../../actions/jobTitleSkillsActions';
import SkillList from './SkillList';

class SkillPage extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.user_positions[0]) {
      this.props.dispatch(loadJobTitleSkills(this.props.user_positions[0].job_title_id));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SkillList skills={this.props.job_title_skills} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SkillPage.propTypes = {
  job_title_skills: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  user_positions: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    job_title_skills: state.job_title_skills,
    user_positions: state.user_positions
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SkillPage);
```

`state.user_positions` = `{}` when the component is rendered as a previous component is a form that submits `state.user_positions`. Right after the SkillPage component is rendered, state.user_positions is populated, which I validated in the Redux chrome extension.

The problem is this SkillPage component is not automatically re-rendering. I expect the component to automatically detect `state.user_positions` has changed and rerun componentDidMount, which would then dispatch `loadJobTitleSkills()`.

What am I doing wrong here? Why isn't my component re-rendering whenever state.user_positions is modified?

userPositionReducer.js:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {}

export default function userPositionReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.CREATE_USERPOSITION_SUCCESS:
      return action.user_position
    case types.LOAD_USERPOSITION_SUCCESS:
      return action.user_positions
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

jobTitleSkillsReducer.js:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = []

export default function jobTitleSkillsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_JOBTITLESKILLS_SUCCESS:
     return action.job_title_skills
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

### Update

I was able to get it to "work" by adding the following to my SkillPage component and removing componentDidMount()

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.user_positions[0] && this.props.job_title_skills.length === 0) {
      this.props.dispatch(loadJobTitleSkills(this.props.user_positions[0].job_title_id));
    }
  }
```

This feels super hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

### Update 2

```
Working with this added:

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.user_positions && nextProps.user_positions.length > 0) {
      if (this.props.user_positions[0] !== nextProps.user_positions[0]) {
        this.props.dispatch(loadJobTitleSkills(nextProps.user_positions[0].job_title_id));
      }
    }
  }
```

This solution still feels super hacky.

### Update 3 - Adding Action Creators

jobTitleSkillsActions.js

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import JobTitleSkillsApi from '../api/JobTitleSkillsApi';

export function loadJobTitleSkillsSuccess(job_title_skills) {
  return {type: types.LOAD_JOBTITLESKILLS_SUCCESS, job_title_skills};
}

export function loadJobTitleSkills(job_title_id) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return JobTitleSkillsApi.getAllJobTitleSkills(job_title_id).then(skills => {
      dispatch(loadJobTitleSkillsSuccess(skills));
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

UserPositionActions.js

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import userPositionsApi from '../api/UserPositionsApi';

export function createUserPositionSuccess(user_position) {
  return {type: types.CREATE_USERPOSITION_SUCCESS, user_position};
}

export function loadUserPositionSuccess(user_positions) {
  return {type: types.LOAD_USERPOSITION_SUCCESS, user_positions};
}

export function loadUserPositions() {
  // console.log('actions: loadUserPosition')
  return function(dispatch) {
    return userPositionsApi.getAllUserPositions().then(user_positions => {
      dispatch(loadUserPositionSuccess(user_positions));
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}

export function createUserPosition(user_position) {
  // console.log('actions: createUserPosition')
  return function (dispatch) {
    return userPositionsApi.createUserPosition(user_position).then(responseUserPosition => {
      dispatch(createUserPositionSuccess(responseUserPosition));
      return responseUserPosition;
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: If I move my dispatch into componentDidUpdate() then it works but it continue in a render/query loop never ending.

Comment: I see your reducers are just returning the values from the action, like `return action.job_title_skills`.  How are you constructing the action object?  What do your action creators look like?  If you're directly mutating the existing array in the action creator and then adding it to the action, you're never actually creating a new array reference, and `connect` will think nothing has changed.

Comment: @markerikson just added the Action Creators, does this help?

Comment: A bit.  Does look like the values are coming in from the API, so you're not accidentally re-using them.  Re-reading your question, it looks like @Shubham Khatri's answer is correct. The main issue is that you're expecting `componentDidMount` to run twice, which won't - it only runs once when the component is created and attached.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ComponentDidMount` lifeCycle function is only executed once, at the time of component Mount. What you want is the `componentWillReceiveProps` function which too which gets executed on every prop change

Do this

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.user_positions[0] ) {
      this.props.dispatch(loadJobTitleSkills(this.props.user_positions[0].job_title_id));
    }
  }
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

     if (this.props.user_positions[0] !== nextProps.userPositions[0]) {
      this.props.dispatch(loadJobTitleSkills(this.props.user_positions[0].job_title_id));
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi, that errors w `Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: ok I was able to get it to work but fixing a couple typos, added to the question... Is this really the right way to React-redux to handle this type of situation?

Comment: Yes this is the way to do it. Also you can edit my answer the typos you correct, Also consider accepting the answer if it helped