# Local state in redux is not updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, local

There is state in my class, updated with two functions:

```js
export default class ProductList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            productIdListToEdit: [],
        }
    }


handleCheckClick = (elementId, e) => {
  ...
        this.setState({ productIdListToEdit: tempList })
    }


checkAllAction = () => {
  ...
        this.setState({ productIdListToEdit: [1, 2, 3] })
    }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

This state is transfer in return to class:

```js
 <GroupEditButton
 productIdListToEdit={this.state.productIdListToEdit}   >
```

After changing state with "handleCheckClick " Inside Class state is changing, but after using "checkAllAction", local state still changes, but deeper(in lower Class-EditButton) is like a frozen - in state  productIdListToEdit doesn't change.

```js
export default class EditButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            productIdListToEdit: this.props.productIdListToEdit,
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.productIdListToEdit)
        if (this.state.productIdListToEdit.length > 0) {
            return (
                ...
            )
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but deeper is like a frozen"? "Nothing" what needs to change? Could please add more details?

Comment: In EditButton class state is reading from upper. And when i Click on "checkAllAction " , state doesn't change - it is always the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426509/react-redux-component-is-not-automatically-re-rendering-on-state-change-why/44428014#44428014

Comment: use `componentWillReceiveProps` and reset state there on every props change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor is only called once on initialization of the class.  In order to see updates, just use `props` directly:

```
export default class EditButton extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.productIdListToEdit)
        if (this.props.productIdListToEdit.length > 0) {
            return (
                ...
            )
        }
    }
```